# Rename Control in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to rename a WPF Control in XAML and want all References in C# Code-behind to be renamed. Like I can do in class files with F2.

A free solution would be nice. I know that [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does the Job, but ReSharper is not free.

If this is possible, how do I do it?

Comment: when using mvvm and binding you dont need control names at all in code behind (most time...)

Comment: some People can not choose on which Project they work.

Comment: just curious to know.. why would you want to change Name of control at runtime...

Comment: Do you mean in design time? Use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Rename.html).

Comment: @nit obv. design time

Comment: @galenus ReSharper is not free

Comment: @Anubis1233 In case you are financially constrained, you are probably out of luck. As far as I know, there are no XAML refactoring improvements in VS2013, and I suspect there will be none in the VS-next as well.

Comment: If you just want to keep the xaml name in sync with the code behind name, you have to do it the other way around - rename it in code behind, and this will rename it in the file xaml as well.

Comment: @Bohoo Thanks, that works!  I thought you could only rename things from the C# declaration (which doesn't seem exist for WPF controls), but I see now that you can rename things from any reference in the C# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 solutions for you:

- Open your solution in Expression Blend for Visual Studio (bundled with VS2013) and rename the control using the Properties window. Blend is very good at renaming XAML elements.
- Just rename it and fix the compile errors by hand.
- If you are confident that your control name is unique, do a find & replace operation upon it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While I first thought it worked. The Solution (1) with Blend did not rename the Code-Behind

Comment: @Anubis1233 bugger! On the plus side, it will rename all the XAML (the hard part imo) and you get nice clean compile errors for the code behind :) You might be stuck - a fully automatic solution may not exist. Often in programming, we have to resist the temptation to find/write a program to do a mindless, thankless task; throw on some music and blitz it by hand!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the **Refactor Rename** command in the C# code, it will rename it in XAML also.

`Edit menu` > `Refactor` > `Rename`, at least in VS2015

Unfortunately this same command doesn't work from XAML (it does nothing).